# Turn on one by one the LEDs of a Neopixel rgb LEDs strip for each detection at the same distance from an Ultrasonic Distance Sensor (HC-SR04)

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit, rgb-led, neopixel, hc-sr04

For this project I seek to create a counter of water glasses we drank throughout the day.
I use for this an **Arduino UNO card**, a **Piezo buzzer** and a **Neopixel rgb LEDs strip** (5 LEDs for this test).

Aside from the last 2 LEDs that only light up to indicate to the user that his presence is considered by the product, I would like that when the HC-SR04 first detects our glass of water between 0 and 5cm (*cheers!*), the first LED lights up and stays on. When the first LED is on and the HC-SR04 detects a second time our water glass is between 0 and 5cm, then the second LED lights up and stays on as well. And so on.
For each glass detected between 0 and 5cm, a slight sound sounds through the piezo buzzer.

By using the **Adafruit Neopixel library** ([download here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel)), I manage to make everything work as I see fit. However, I still have trouble programming if the LED *n* is on then the *n+1* LED lights up at the next detection between 0 and 5cm, without all the LEDs lighting at the same time in a single detection.

I recently tried to use a boolean to identify when the LED *n* is *true* (ON/HIGH), but unsuccessfully. I leave you my code as is by thanking you for any help you can bring me.

See my layout and my code below:
[image: Arduino UNO + Components layout]

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;
const int buzzer = 11;

#define dinPin 4
#define numLEDs 5

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(numLEDs, dinPin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

long duration;
int distance;

int blue;
int green;
int off;

boolean lightLED = false;


void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.setBrightness(80);
  strip.show();

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;

  uint32_t blue = strip.Color(0, 100, 255);
  uint32_t green = strip.Color(0, 255, 20);
  uint32_t off = strip.Color(0, 0, 0);

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // LED 1 + Buzzer
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (distance <= 5) {

    if (! lightLED) {
      strip.setPixelColor(0, blue);
      strip.show();
      delay(0);
    }

    else {
      lightLED = false;
    }

    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    tone(buzzer, 400, 100);
    delay(75);
    tone(buzzer, 600, 100);
    delay(75);
    tone(buzzer, 800, 100);
    delay(75);
    noTone(buzzer);

  }

  else {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  }

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // LED 2
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (lightLED && distance <= 5) {

    lightLED = true;

    if (! lightLED) {
      strip.setPixelColor(1, blue);
      strip.show();
      delay(0);
    }
  }

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // DETECT USER PRESENCE
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (distance >= 6 && distance <= 20) {
    strip.setPixelColor(3, green);
    strip.setPixelColor(4, green);
    strip.show();
    delay(0);
  }

  else {
    strip.setPixelColor(3, off);
    strip.setPixelColor(4, off);
    strip.show();
    delay(0);
  }

  // Voir la distance dans le moniteur
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distance);
}
```

Sorry for the code that is a bit rough, I am a beginner but I hope not to have lost you in my explanations (I lose myself in my code…).

Thanks,

Thibaut

Comment: You need to debounce the detection.

Comment: Thanks for answering @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, can you be more explicit with a piece of code or something? As I said, I'm a beginner and I have trouble seeing what you mean.

Comment: Search for "debouncing" on Google.  There are many ways to do it in hardware or software.  I doubt you will find someone who has debounced a HC-SR04 in software for an Arduino, you will have to piece together bits from various sources.  Debouncing switches is probably the most common.  You might be a beginner, but if you have written that much you'll be able to write a debouncing function and it will be more 'fun' than copy and paste, because you will understand it.  If you get stuck though, come back with what you have.

Comment: Yes you're totally right @Matt :)
I'll see this as soon as possible and will come back here if I struggle to do what I want.
Similarly, I will not fail to share the result if it's successful. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Thib Can you share your solution here as an answer (which is encouraged in cases like this)?  I had a similar idea for combining range-detection with the WS2812 so I'm interested in how your project came out.